# Other ways to say 'Here I am pouring my heart out' to my best friend

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Okay, so I am currently in the midst of trying to come clean and confess my guilt to my best friend. I messed up and gossiped with another friend about something he trusted me with. I can't properly detail just how awful I feel, nor can I measure the depth of this horrid dark pit in my stomach that has manifested around the guilt I carry.

What I say and how is very important to me. We have only been communicating via text as of late, and whenever I open up about how bad I feel and how I want to right my wrongs, he does not reply.

So I am looking for (I think) a similar idiom or other phrase to use in place of

> **Here I am pouring my heart out**, and you can't even so much as reply.

Come clean? I don't know. I just want to find a phrase with a little more spice! Haha I put a lot of work into every text...

Thanks

Comment: You may get a lot more help on SE: Interpersonal Skills.

Answer (score 1):

Come clean would work...But you mentioned you want to right your wrongs, so consider

['make amends'](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/make--amends)

```
to compensate, as for an injury, loss, or insult
```

I'd like to add that, although this isn't the Interpersonal Skills stack, you seem to be frustrated with your friend not replying. If you are the one in the wrong, they do not necessarily owe you a response. You might have to practice patience in them replying or even forgiving you.

Good luck